# How do I set column range as variable in Excel using a macro?

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have a matrix of dates with each one representing a different task, project, planned/actual start/finish. Please see the attached picture:

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWPJ1.png)

I have left everything in general terms as the actual names are confidential to my company. Anyhow, every row and column tells a different piece of information. Every two rows tells what project a date belongs to, and every row tell whether that date is a start or finish date. Every two columns tells what task the date belongs to, and every column states whether the date is a predicted date or an actual one.

Setting aside, what I am trying to do with this data is create a macro that will search all of these dates within a range set by the user, and list each date with the aforementioned information. So far, I have a code does this for individual rows:

```
Sub Sort_By_Date()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim i As Integer


StartDate = Range("F61").Value
EndDate = Range("G61").Value

'Clears out cells
Range("Z74:AD200").Value = ""

m = 74

For i = 71 To 200
If Range("C" & i).Value >= StartDate And Range("C" & i).Value <= EndDate Then
Range("Z" & m).Value = Range("C" & i).Value
Range("AA" & m).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
Range("AB" & m).Value = Range("C69")
Range("AC" & m).Value = Range("B" & i)
Range("AD" & m).Value = Range("C70")
m = m + 1
End If

If Range("D" & i).Value >= StartDate And Range("D" & i).Value <= EndDate Then
Range("Z" & m).Value = Range("D" & i).Value
Range("AA" & m).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
Range("AB" & m).Value = Range("D69")
Range("AC" & m).Value = Range("B" & i)
Range("AD" & m).Value = Range("D70")
m = m + 1
End If

If Range("E" & i).Value >= StartDate And Range("E" & i).Value <= EndDate Then
Range("Z" & m).Value = Range("E" & i).Value
Range("AA" & m).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
Range("AB" & m).Value = Range("E69")
Range("AC" & m).Value = Range("B" & i)
Range("AD" & m).Value = Range("E70")
m = m + 1
End If
```

...
...
...
Hopefully you can see the pattern here.

I can keep copying and pasting that If Then statement for every column, but there has to be a more efficient way to do it. I am fairly new to Excel macros (someone else actually wrote the basis of that code), so I am not sure how to make it do what I want it to. I imagine it will involve making the column letters into numbers, and then into variables, but I just don't know. I have tried looking it up, but I am having trouble applying what I found to my specific application.

So my main question: How do I get that If Then statement to repeat for every column of data I have without having to copy and paste it a million times?

Comment: So, if every other column has dates you want, you can specify the step of a For statement, e.g., For i = 2 to 100 Step 2.  Within each For statement, an If/Then statement can be used, or sums, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you simply need a nested for loop:

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim i As Integer, c as integer


StartDate = Range("F61").Value
EndDate = Range("G61").Value

'Clears out cells
Range("Z74:AD200").Value = ""

m = 74

'From column C to column AD
For c = 3 TO 30
  For i = 71 To 200
    If Range("C" & i).Value >= StartDate And Range("C" & i).Value <= EndDate Then
      Range("Z" & m).Value = cells(i,c).Value
      Range("AA" & m).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
      Range("AB" & m).Value = cells(69,c).value
      Range("AC" & m).Value = Range("B" & i)
      Range("AD" & m).Value = cells(70,c).value
      m = m + 1
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I was looking for was this:

```
Sub Sort_By_Date()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim rwMin As Integer
Dim colMin As Integer
Dim rwMax As Integer
Dim colMax As Integer
Dim rwIndex As Integer
Dim colIndex As Integer

StartDate = Range("F61").Value
EndDate = Range("G61").Value

rwMin = 4
colMin = 3
rwMax = 37
colMax = 68

Range("L44:R2600").Value = ""

m = 44

For colIndex = colMin To colMax

    For rwIndex = rwMin To rwMax

    If Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value >= StartDate And Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value <= EndDate Then
    Range("L" & m).Value = Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value
    Range("M" & m).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 1).Value
    Range("N" & m).Value = Cells(2, colIndex).Value
    Range("O" & m).Value = Cells(1, colIndex).Value
    Range("P" & m).Value = Cells(rwIndex, 2).Value
    Range("Q" & m).Value = Cells(3, colIndex).Value
    m = m + 1
    End If

    Next rwIndex


Next colIndex

End Sub
```

Basically, I needed to switch from using `Range.Value` to `Cells.Value` and then uses indexes. However, I seem to now have a separate issue of causing a runtime error with another function that I want to include, but that's a topic for a different post. It works right now without that function, though. Thanks for your input!